# How to install and setup hybris opencommerce framework?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need the hybris-commerce-suite-5.0.4.0.zip(API) and install setup of the framework.I need to understand hybris how is it made.Also help me with other java ecommerce supported frameworks made over spring.

Comment: Follow Trails https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/hybris+5+Developer+Training+Trails+-+Part+I+-+Core

Answer (score 2):

Most people learn hybris by starting with the hybris Core Trail (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/d5582c7cd2d5443891003ed071b26193.html).

The hybris Core Trail is a set of exercises that will teach you about the Hybris core functionality.  The Core Trail is the most fundamental trail you'll find in the selection of trails(i.e., Core, Commerce, Promotion Engine Trail); if you don't know where to start - start at the Core Trail.

The aim of those technical trails is to provide Hybris trainees with a tutorial trail covering the main themes and best-practices of the hybris core platform.

The material can be used both in a training course and at home for self-study.

The zipped source code is based on Hybris' Cuppy and CuppyTrail Extensions, which can be downloaded from here:

```
cuppy.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppy.zip)
```

If you want the complete source code of the final solution, you can get it here:

```
cuppytrail.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppytrail.zip)
cuppytrailhmc.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppytrailhmc.zip)
cuppytrailfrontend.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppytrailfrontend.zip)
cuppytrailcockpit.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppytrailcockpit.zip)
cuppytrailbackoffice.zip (https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/downloads/Trails/Core/cuppytrailbackoffice.zip)
```

Here is a high level of the steps in the Core Trail:

Tasks

```
Installing Java

Installing Eclipse

Setting up the Eclipse Workspace and Installing Hybris

    Download Hybris Platform Binaries

    Build from Console

    Import into Eclipse

    Preparing Eclipse's Ant View

    Debugging from Eclipse

Running Hybris

    Start the Server

    Initialize the System using Hybris Admin Console (HAC)

    Explore Hybris
Adding cuppy

    Download the Cuppy Extension

    Resulting Folder Structure

    Tell Hybris about the Cuppy extension

    Rebuild the System

    Update the System

Required/Helpful Reading

Summary
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Hybris license you can get the download from the [hybris wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com). However, 5.0 is an outdated release, you should not use that.

The best way to dive into hybris is, as commented by Shreshtt Bhatt, to follow the [trails in the wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Release+5+Trails).